# Crontab not working for one shell script among set of scripts

Tags: shell, unix, cron, scheduling

I have scheduled 5 jobs using crontab and all the jobs except one is getting executed. the entry pattern goes like this

```
05 08 * * * /appllib/int/exe/script1.sh
05 08 * * * /appllib/int/exe/script2.sh
10 08 * * * /appllib/int/exe/script3.sh
40 08 * * * /appllib/int/exe/script4.sh
30 07 * * * /appllib/int/exe/script5.sh
```

Also i have a newline after the last entry. All except `script5.sh` is getting executed.

Comment: Have you checked for new mail for the user who owns this crontab?

Comment: Can you run the script manually? Is it's execution permission bits set correctly? Also for group/other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
chmod 755 /appllib/int/exe/script5.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, its because of the access issues.